# Make userform reusable and keep on top

Tags: excel, vba

Following is the background:
I have a “Home” sheet which has a command button which shows a userform when clicked.
The userform takes coordinate inputs on text boxes and it creates rectangles of a new sheet “Rectangles”, once OK command button on userform is clicked.
Now, I want the “Rectangles” sheet to be seen when the OK command button on userform is clicked.
Also, I want to keep the userform on top, incase user sees that a particular rectangle is not in the desired place and wants to update the coordinates.

I have the following code on the main sub

```
With rect_box
   .StartUpPosition = 0
   'Position Userform to the centre of screen
   .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
   .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
   .Width = 240
   .Height = 460
   .Show
End With
```

In the userform rect_box code ok command button, I have the following code

```
x1 = x1box1.Value 'x1box1, x2box2... are all textbox names
y1 = y1box2.Value
x2 = x2box3.Value
y2 = y2box4.Value
Unload me
```

I then use the x1, y1, x2, y2 in another sub, to create rectangles on the “Rectangles” sheet.
Towards the end of the sub, I put the following to show the sheet.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rectangles").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rectangles").Activate
```

Now, if I don’t use “Unload me”, then once I click OKcommand button, I cannot move ahead with the code.

If I make the userform nonmodal (.show False), then the “Rectangles” sheet is shown and I have the userform on top of it as I intend. However, I am unable to reuse it to change values and reuse the command to reposition the rectangles.

```
'Option 1:
    With rect_box
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        'Position Userform to the centre of screen
        .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
        .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
        .Width = 240
        .Height = 460
        .Show.False
    End With
```

The whole macro runs, without giving user a chance to input values in the text box in the first place. The sheet has no rectangles and userform is overlayed. Now, when input is added and ok is clicked after, nothing happens, but the userform closes.

```
    'Option 2:
        With rect_box
            .StartUpPosition = 0
            'Position Userform to the centre of screen
            .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
            .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
            .Width = 240
            .Height = 460
            .Show
        End With
rect_box.show False
```

User can input values once. The sheet shows up with rectangles and has the userform overlayed. But then the user cannot reuse the form. Pressing ok does nothing but close the userform.

How do I go around it?

Thank you for the support.

Comment: Have you tried to show the form Non-modal?

Comment: Yes, I did. I edited the comment to show the results in two different options.

Comment: There are quite some things unclear. Where are the x and y variables defined? Is `rect_box` a created instance of the form or it that the name of your form and you use the default instance? When you use `unload`, the object is destroyed. When you use the default instance, the next time you use it, a complete new object is created automatically. When you use an form object that you created by yourself, you need to create it again.

Comment: x and y are Public variables defined in the "Rectangles_creation" Sub. (The one which positions the rectangles on the "Rectangles" sheet.)
I created the form myself with 10 text boxes and an Ok command button.
I understand what you are saying. I was trying to find a work around. If i dont use 'unload' then "Rectangles" sheet doesnt view at all

Comment: Okay, instead of unload me, I used `hide` and have `rect_box.show False` on the main sub. Now, the macro runs as intended. I get to "Rectangles" sheet with the rect_box userform overlayed with the values entered in text boxes (since it is not destroyed)
But, as before, I cant reuse the userform to change rectangle positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x1 = x1box1.Value 'x1box1, x2box2... are all textbox names
y1 = y1box2.Value
x2 = x2box3.Value
y2 = y2box4.Value
'Unload me
```

You can potentially remove the unload me section. This will let you keep the values in play. You can also use the `UserForm.Hide` to keep the userform out of view.